# How to incorporate user code into my own app?

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions

I've been working on a DMX lighting app for a while now, and I feel like I've learned a lot about software design along the way.  For example, data hiding, with private members and access functions, is a great way to guarantee that a class can only be used as intended, thread-safely, but it can also be overdone to the point of becoming obnoxious and hard to expand on.  It's good to a point, but...anyway, back to the question.

What I'm thinking about now, is how to incorporate user code into it, so as to make it completely free-form.  I have a certain way that I like to run a show, but it's certainly not the only way, and each way to do it has its own capabilities and limitations that may or may not work well with a particular workflow.

So rather than try and come up with everything on my own that a user might want to do, and have to say, "I'm sorry, you can't do that," a lot, I think it'd be better to give them a turing-complete programming language of some kind and let them have fun with it.  I might also give them a set of copy-pastable source code that does some useful things, and a "code wizard" that can be trusted to create something that at least compiles, but my vision for it is for each knowledgeable user to create their own tools so that the app works the way that they want:

- Preset scene on each button, mutually exclusive with timed crossfade
- Preset scene on each fader, as mixable scene masters
- No preset scenes, but each control has its own effect to be played live in any combination
- Custom automation, as simple or complex as desired
- Etc.
- Mixtures of all the above

The preset scenes might use built-in functions without user-programming, but the rest is such a blank canvas that I can't see a way around it.

---

The version that I have now has a bytecode interpreter that runs a custom instruction set, similar to what I understand of x86 being designed for hand-optimized assembly, and motivated by some other novice-oriented languages that struck me as custom-interpreted assembly.  But because there's (of course) no existing toolchain for my invention, I had to write my own, which turned out to be a lot of complicated GUI work.  I got (most of?) the bugs out of it, but it's always been a mess: about half of the total source code is for a mouse-only editor that is barely usable, and the interpreter seems to bog down when I try to do a lot with it.
(I haven't counted native instructions per interpreted instruction, but it's definitely a lot!)

So I'm wondering about using `Basic`, `C`, `C++`, `Python`, or something else that already has a decent toolchain and incorporate that into my app in place of my own hack.  The development environment would appear to be a part of the app - or maybe it actually is, no visibly external tools either way - but still use an existing, mature toolchain.

The goals from the user's perspective are:

- Performance (execution speed / complexity without bogging down)
- An existing community for help so they don't have to swamp me with everything

The challenges that I see are:

- Transferring control from my code to a module that I didn't write and guaranteeing that I get it back
- Accessing dynamic data sets that are managed by my code, without crashing or breaking references to things that still exist:

  - `Audio_Analyzer[channel][band]` (static, read-only)
  - `MIDI_Velocity[channel][note]` (static, read-only)
  - `Physical_Controls["name"]` (populated by discovery, read/write: motorized faders, lighted buttons, etc.)
  - `Fixtures["name"].Features["name"]` (user-created/deleted/modified at any time, read/write, most Fixtures include their own programming to translate Features into DMX)
  - `DMX_In[universe][channel]` (user-adjustable universe count, static channel count, read-only)
  - `DMX_Out[universe][channel]` (user-adjustable universe count, static channel count, read/write)
  - Etc.

---

So...besides the obvious security problem of executing arbitrary code on purpose (don't run it as root), what kind of minefield am I getting myself into?  What's a good way to accomplish my goals?

So far, my development environment has been `C++` and `Qt` on `Lubuntu (x64)`, but I also want this next version to run on `Raspbian (armhf)` as well.  (Raspberry Pi)

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "scriptability". Since you tagged your question with Qt, see [Qt Script](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscript-index.html)

Comment: This question would seem to be way too broad for SO to me. If you think C++ is something that your target audience can deal with, I would start with a traditional plugin system based on dynamically loaded libraries (shared objects/DLLs). That will force you to figure out the necessary interfaces and work with minimal overhead. Scripting is something that could still be added later…

Comment: Yep, you want to connect a scripting language.  Or plug in dynamic libraries but that is harder.  Lua, python, perl, lisp -- you name it someone has used it as a scripting language, and there are piles of examples of how to do it.  Nothing in your question gives enough detail to give us a way to say which one, so... to broad.

Comment: Hmm...too broad...because I didn't know what was possible?  Poorly researched, maybe, but you kinda have to know what to look for first.  So maybe someone could answer along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vague and very broad, but still let me try to answer.
Going by your requirements related to performance and support for a toolchain or library, you can look at PyQt(Python bindings for Qt) library. Using pyqt may prove to be beneficial as you have all the fine controls on the objects passed(Python makes it fun to manipulate/convert/modify objects to desirable output objects) and you still have the performance because of Qt & C++ under the hood. PyQt has an active community and eager to help for any issues/bugs.